# Is there a difference between returning a value and returning an expression in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, return, code-structure

A friend of mine just asked me which of the following two expressions would be the better choice. While I understand the question, and thus the definition of better, is potentially a matter of opinion and thus off-topic; I was keen to understand if there was a good reasoning in favour of one.

```
var count = _.reduce(randomData, function(prefix, businessData){
    return prefix + businessData.length;
}, 0);

return {
    name: randomName,
    pos: position[randomName],
    count: count
};
```

or

```
return {
    name: randomName,
    pos: position[randomName],
    count: 
        _.reduce(randomData, function(prefix, businessData){
            return prefix + businessData.length;
        }, 0)
};
```

Both another colleague and I were in agreement that the first one would be better as it's clearer, potentially easier to debug and more easily understood but outside of that we couldn't justify our choice.

Is there a reason why one would favour returning the value against returning the expression?

Comment: You're not returning an expression. You're returning the result of the reduce function.

Comment: Terminology aside: they’re functionally equivalent. Readability is a perfectly good reason to favour one over the other, though.

Comment: On the subject of subjectivity... :-) I have a friend with just under 30 years professional development experience who rails against `return /*long calculation here*/;` His *opinion* is that `var retVal = /*long calculation here*/; return retVal;` should always be preferred. Since he pointed that out to me years ago, I've never been unhappy when I've followed that advice.

Comment: @RyanO'Hara: Indeed. Readability is in the eye of the beholder, of course. (But I'm with the OP on preferring the first.)

Comment: Thanks all for the input and the great answer @T.J.Crowder. I feared the opinion would be the crux of this question. Would it technically be within the rules if I reworded the title to: "Is there a good reason to prefer returning the result of an expression over returning a variable storing the result?"

Comment: @JohnO'Mahoney: Well, for *me*, it was okay as-is, because just because it asks for a reason to favour one or the other, that doesn't mean that the reason has to be opinion-based. As I mentioned in the answer, I think your debugging point is an objective one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a difference between returning a value and returning an expression in JavaScript?

No, you're returning a value either way. More accurately, from your code examples, you're assigning a value to the `count` property of the object you're returning a reference to either way.

The only difference in your code examples is when `reduce` is called. In the first one, it's called before the construction of the object you're returning begins. In the second, it's called during that construction. There's no difference in what the function then goes on to return, though.

> Is there a reason why one would favour returning the value against returning the expression?

Since the first answer above is "no," the only reasons take us into, or at least very near, the land of opinion.

The closest *objective* measure I can come up with is one of the ones you pointed out: Debugging. With the first one, you can easily see `count` before constructing and returning the object. With the second, that's more difficult.

---

More detail about this object construction thing, in case that was a surprise: JavaScript defines the order that the property initializers in an object initializer are run: Unsurprisingly, they're run in source-code order. So for instance, if we have this code:

```
var num = 0;
function foo() {
    return ++num;
}
var obj = {
    a: foo(),
    b: foo(),
    c: foo()
};
```

...we know for certain that the value of `obj.a` is 1, `obj.b` is 2, and `obj.c` is 3. That's defined by the specification.

Comment: "the land of opinion": the track that didn't quite make it on to Invisible Touch.

Comment: @Andy: Heh, had to check out the track list to get that. :-)